# Don't understand the statement "individual inherited values are not possible with any shorthand property"

Tags: css, inheritance

I saw the following statement at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) website. The page itself is about "border-radius", but I think the statement applies to all shorthand properties.

[image]

I'm not exactly sure what they meant by "individual inherited values are not possible with any shorthand property", could someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the note says, the following is invalid, even though intuitively it looks like it should set two of the corner radii to 0 and two of them to inherit:

```
border-radius:0 0 inherit inherit
```

This is because different shorthands have different grammars making it impossible for multiple `inherit` values to be mixed with other values. You wouldn't be able to determine which of the component properties should inherit, and you wouldn't be able to determine how to parse the remaining values that *aren't* `inherit`.

For example, while the above declaration looks easy enough, consider a `background` declaration:

```
background: inherit inherit #fff
```

There are two `inherit` keywords here, but the `background` shorthand contains a *multitude* of component properties with a complex grammar. It's impossible to determine which two of the longhands other than `background-color` should inherit. You have to tell the browser. Which means writing longhand declarations.

So, `inherit` is defined as a CSS-wide keyword that may only appear by itself in any property declaration, including shorthands. This eliminates any possible ambiguity regardless of whether the property is a longhand property accepting a single value, a longhand property accepting *multiple* values (such as `border-top-left-radius` or `background-size`), or a shorthand property.

See also: [Leaving certain values unchanged when using CSS shorthand properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379919/leaving-certain-values-unchanged-when-using-css-shorthand-properties/9380085#9380085)